# Programatically Generated Bundled Products Not Displaying on Category Page

Tags: php, magento

I'm generating a number of bundled products using Magmi and some custom code:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);


$storeID = 1;
$websiteIDs = array(1);

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

//Get bundled products

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('type')
    //->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'bundle') // simpler..
    ->addFieldToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'bundle')) // simple/configurable etc
;


foreach ($products as $product){

      $parentProduct = clone $product;

    // get all the options of your bundle product assumed as $bundle

    // remove the Selection/Bundle association from database, we need to pass all the others except the one we need to drop

    Mage::getModel('bundle/mysql4_bundle')->dropAllUnneededSelections();

    $options = $product->getTypeInstance()->getOptionsCollection();

    foreach ($options as $option){
          $option->delete();
    }



    $simple_skus = explode(",",$product->getBundledSkus());
    $items = array();
    $selections = array();

    $simple_skus = array_reverse($simple_skus);
    foreach ($simple_skus as $sku){
          if ($sku == '')continue;

          $selectionRawData = array();

          $pos = 0;
          $pos++;
          $productId = $product->getIdBySku($sku);
          $simple =   $product->load($productId);


                $items[] = array(
                'title' => $simple->getName(),
                'parent_id' => $parentProduct->getId(),
                'option_id' => '',
                'delete' => '',
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'required' => ( strpos($sku,'harness') !== false ? 1 : 0),
                'position' => $pos);

            $selections[][] = array(
                'selection_id' => '',
                'option_id' => '',
                'product_id' => $simple->getEntityId(),
                'delete' => '',
                'selection_price_value' => $simple->getPrice(),
                'selection_price_type' => 0,
                'selection_qty' => 1,
                'selection_can_change_qty' => 0,
                'position' => 0);

    }


            Mage::unregister('product');
            Mage::unregister('current_product');
            Mage::register('product', $parentProduct);
            Mage::register('current_product', $parentProduct);
            $parentProduct->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(false);
            $parentProduct->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
```

If you look at it it in the backend, everything appears to be set up correctly, and if you enter the URL you can go directly to a product and it all works, can add it to the basket etc - see http://autosparks.absolute-staging.co.uk/src/trunk/seat-belt-harness.html as an example.

However, even through the products have been assigned to the correct categories, it's not returning any products on categories, or on search.

If I create a bundled product in the backend, using exactly the same values as the generated bundle, and it works and displays as expected.

A few things I have tried:

- I have re-indexed (Many, Many Times)
- I have cleared the cache
- I have truncated all the magento product tables, flat tables etc, and re-imported from scratch
- I have tried duplicating one of the imported products and saving a new product from it
- The products are all in stock
- The bundled product has a Visibility of Search, Catalog
- The simple products have a visibility of Not Individually Visible

I'm sure I've missed something obvious, a table I need to update or something, but I'm not sure what!

Comment: If you hit save on one of these new products from admin with re-index on save enabled, does it then show up? If so, it's a missing attribute somewhere that you've missed. Need to compare a good product against bad in every catalog product entity table and bundle ones to find missing attribute is my bet.

Comment: Hi @AshleySwatton thanks for your message. No, re-saving the product from the backend doesn't help sadly.

Comment: Sadly the solution will be in the db somewhere. Manually create an identical product as to what your generating in admin and trace it through every table in the db that begins with catalog_. Start with the product_entity table and work outwards from there. Note down all the attribute ids and values being used for a working product vs a non until you find something different and manually add or change it for the bad product, reindex and retest. The catalog_product_website has caught me out before. Good Luck.

Comment: Am also facing same problem, the difference I can find is when i save product from back end, it is appearing in search and also, after saving from backend, a new entery in coming in catalogsearch_fulltext  , anybody can advise me how can i overcome this issue, I could not simply put entry in the table..

Comment: Check if catalog_product_index_price values are empty. In product listing there is an inner join with that table.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue with my programmatically created bundle products: not appearing in catalog or search results, but able to see the product when accessing by direct url.

As @MagePsycho mentionned, this was caused by missing entries inthe `catalog_product_index_price` and `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_idx` tables.

Adding a call to `$bundle_product->setData('price_type', 0);` before saving the bundled product fixed the issue.

However, I see you are getting your bundled product by cloning another bundled product, so I am not sure if this solution is going to work. Please have a try.